# Gas cost for ether transfer < 9000

Tags: evm

According to the Yellow Paper, creating a transaction costs 21000 gas (regardless if it contains value) and creating a message call with non-zero call value costs at at least 9000 gas. Yet when I call `Contract`'s default function in Remix (uses `ethereumjs-vm`) with a value of 1 ether, the entire transaction costs 28562. That means 7562 for execution. How could it be less than 9000?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Helper {
    function () external payable {}
}

contract Contract {        
    function () external payable {
        [insert helper address here].transfer (1 ether);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please cite (give a link) to the `at least 9000 gas` restriction?

Comment: sure! It's called G_{callvalue} on page 25 of the [Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf#page=25) I say "at least" 9000 because there are usually other costs associated with CALL's (e.g. for transaction data).

Comment: That applies for `[insert helper address here].call.value(1 ether)` I believe.

Comment: I think it applies here too. Look at what opcode is generated, it is still a CALL call. ;)

Comment: I did, there's a whole additional bunch of opcodes when you replace `addr.transfer(1 ether)` with `addr.call.value(1 ether)("")`.

Comment: indeed. but there's the same CALL opcode with the same call value, isn't there? :)